# How to test in browser android version/style?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

after app installing from official site: ionic start myApp tabs, by default i see ios app, but how to open android version? 
I can emulate androuid via android emulator, app is rebuilt into android version automatically. How do this in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ionic serve --lab` command can be used to run in browser. it will give a dispaly of android and ios together.if you want to run on physical device you can do it using `ionic run android` command.before this you have to run `ionic build android` command also android sdk should be installed in your system. you can also run using an app called `Phonegap` which is avilabe in playstore. but for this your system and phone should be in same wireless network.